# code format mess up in Netbeans IDE

Tags: php

I did few PHP coding on Dreamweaver.But the code format is completly messed up when open the code in Netbeans IDE.

Is there anyone can help me?

Many thanks

Comment: Please explain what EXACTLY is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

in Netbeans, you can do Alt + Shift + F (or Menu->Source->Format) which formats your code automatically.

Comment: If this fails, you're usually missing a `)` or `}`

Comment: Netbeans does not understand custom template engines, so if you use a php file with html content (sort of like smarty but not being smarty) like this -http://pastebin.com/fBGZ5bQQ- then netbeans doesnt seem able to get it right, while Geany handles it with no problem at all

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to go to :

`Tools > Options > Formatting`

and set the indendation to 4 spaces, instead of 8